# C++ template non-type parameter with condition

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have non-type template with function pointer defined as:

```
template<typename T>
using CallbackFn = T (*)(T);

template <CallbackFn<float> Fn>
static void run(float * data, size_t dataLen)
{
    float dataMax = Fn(data[0]);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < dataLen; i++)
    {
        dataMax = std::max(dataMax, Fn(data[i]));
    }
    printf("%f\n", dataMax);
};

float * someData = new float[10];
run<std::sin>(someData, 10);
run<std::cos>(someData, 10);
```

Is possible to do something like:

```
template <typename T, CallbackFn<std::is_same<T, int> ? float : double> Fn>
static void run(T * data, size_t dataLen)
{
    T dataMax = Fn(data[0]);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < dataLen; i++)
    {
        dataMax = std::max(dataMax, Fn(data[i]));
    }
    printf("%f\n", dataMax);
};

int * someDataInt = new int[10];
run<int, std::sin>(someDataInt, 10);
```

It is a stupid example with `int`, but my actuall code is more complex and I am looking if there is a way how to do the `is_same` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
CallbackFn<std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, float, double>>
```